# nginx reverse proxy for radicale : 403 forbidden

Tags: nginx, permissions, reverse-proxy

Before getting started I configured [Radicale](https://radicale.org/) to run on its own without any security and could access the WebUI on the specified IP:port so things were working.  I then wanted to use a reverse proxy and SSL certificates to make things more secure so turned to their [clear and simple documentation](https://radicale.org/proxy/).

I've added the following to my `server{...}` definition under `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`...

```
       #####################################################################
       ## Radicle (https://radicale.org/proxy/)                           ##
       #####################################################################
       location /radicale/ {                                                
           proxy_pass           http://localhost:9468/;
           proxy_set_header     X-Script-Name /radicale;                    
           proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
           proxy_set_header     X-Remote-User $remote_user;                 
           auth_basic           "Radicale - Password Required";             
           auth_basic_user_file /etc/radicle/htpasswd;                      
           proxy_ssl_certificate         /etc/radicale/client_cert.pem;     
           proxy_ssl_certificate_key     /etc/radicale/client_key.pem;      
           proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/radicale/server_cert.pem;     
       }
```

...and have generated all the certificates.  If I go to `https://example.org/radicale/` I'm asked to log in and can do so with my user credentials.  Unfortunately I then get `403: Forbidden` :-/

My `/etc/radicale/conf` is as follows

```
[server]
[server]
hosts = 127.0.0.1:9468
ssl = True
certificate = /etc/radicale/server_cert.pem
key = /etc/radicale/server_key.pem
certificate_authority = /etc/radicale/client_cert.pem
[encoding]
[auth]
type = http_x_remote_user
htpasswd_filename = /etc/radicale/users
htpasswd_encryption = bcrypt
[rights]
[storage]
[web]
[logging]
[headers]
```

(if an option isn't listed its the default).

First thought was its a permissions issue on the `filesystem_folder = /var/lib/radicale/collections` so I modified these to be `radicale:http` (as nginx runs as `http` on this Arch Linux system)...

```
# l /var/lib/radicale/
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x  3 radicale http 4.0K Aug  7 07:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root     root 4.0K Aug 12 08:07 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 radicale http 4.0K Aug  7 08:18 collections
# l /var/lib/radicale/collections/
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x 3 radicale http 4.0K Aug  7 08:18 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 radicale http 4.0K Aug  7 07:35 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 radicale http 4.0K Aug  7 08:18 collection-root
-rwxrwxr-x 1 radicale http    0 Aug  7 08:18 .Radicale.lock
# l /var/lib/radicale/collections/collection-root/
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x 3 radicale http 4.0K Aug  7 08:18 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 radicale http 4.0K Aug  7 08:18 ..
drwxrwxr-x 4 radicale http 4.0K Aug  7 08:20 user
# l /var/lib/radicale/collections/collection-root/user/
total 16K
drwxrwxr-x 4 radicale http 4.0K Aug  7 08:20 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 radicale http 4.0K Aug  7 08:18 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 radicale http 4.0K Aug  7 08:19 86487dd0-1ca2-8183-b1b8-0bc7933792d2
drwxrwxr-x 2 radicale http 4.0K Aug  7 13:46 bd050325-a411-5d0a-625b-d8569b442441
# l /var/lib/radicale/collections/collection-root/user/*
/var/lib/radicale/collections/collection-root/user/86487dd0-1ca2-8183-b1b8-0bc7933792d2:
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x 2 radicale http 4.0K Aug  7 08:19 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 radicale http 4.0K Aug  7 08:20 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 radicale http  165 Aug  7 08:19 .Radicale.props

/var/lib/radicale/collections/collection-root/user/bd050325-a411-5d0a-625b-d8569b442441:
total 12K
drwxrwxr-x 2 radicale http 4.0K Aug  7 13:46 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 radicale http 4.0K Aug  7 08:20 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 radicale http  216 Aug  7 13:46 .Radicale.props
```

But no joy, still get `403 : Forbidden`, so now I'm stumped as to what to try.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: Does the 403 Forbidden error come from nginx?

Comment: Yes it does, its what shows up in the browser,  its "403 Forbidden" followed by a horizontal rule, under which is "nginx/1.16.0".

Comment: OK, check the nginx error log to find out why it happened.

Comment: Not at home but managed to SSH from phone & check looks like it's a permission issue on the certificate files, will try amending that when next at a computer. Thanks for the obvious sanity check, I'd only been keeping an eye on the access log.

Comment: Fixing permissions on `/etc/radicale/users` sorted it but I then hit a problem as it appears [bcrypt is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35834603/1444043).  Having switched to md5 I now have a SSL error between nginx and radicale, but thats a separate issue that I'll start a new thread for.  Thanks for the pointer, I'll make sure to check error as well as access logs in the future.

Comment: This is likely irrelevant for slackline, but the 403 does appear as well, if X-Script-Name is not matching radicales uri...